# is there any way to download file in chunk using capacitorjs?

Tags: ionic-framework, download, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

i want to download file in chunks but capicatorjs Filesystem not handle large file so how can i download file in chunks using capicatorjs

i search in google and suggested @qrclip/capacitor-file-chunk and @capacitor-community/file-chunk npm package but not found